# I can't create a new rails app, issue with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

It was working fine before, i don't know why now it's not working. I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is what i get when i run the following commands :

```
> ruby -v

ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]


> rails -v 

Rails 6.0.2.1
```

And the problem occurs when i use this basic command to create a new rails app :

```
> rails new MY-APP-TEST

create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/franck/code/BTC1M/MY-APP-TEST/.git/
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/javascript/channels/consumer.js
      create  app/javascript/channels/index.js
      create  app/javascript/packs/application.js
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/yarn
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/spring.rb
      create  config/storage.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/master.key
      append  .gitignore
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/pids
      create  tmp/pids/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  storage
      create  storage/.keep
      create  tmp/storage
      create  tmp/storage/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb
         run  bundle install
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 13.0.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 1.7.0
Using minitest 5.13.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using zeitwerk 2.2.2
Using activesupport 6.0.2.1
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.9.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.7
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.5
Using loofah 2.4.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 6.0.2.1
Using rack 2.0.8
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 6.0.2.1
Using nio4r 2.5.2
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.4
Using websocket-driver 0.7.1
Using actioncable 6.0.2.1
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 6.0.2.1
Using activemodel 6.0.2.1
Using activerecord 6.0.2.1
Using mimemagic 0.3.3
Using marcel 0.3.3
Using activestorage 6.0.2.1
Using mini_mime 1.0.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailbox 6.0.2.1
Using actionmailer 6.0.2.1
Using actiontext 6.0.2.1
Using public_suffix 4.0.1
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using msgpack 1.3.1
Using bootsnap 1.4.5
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using byebug 11.0.1
Using regexp_parser 1.6.0
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 3.29.0
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using ffi 1.11.3
Using jbuilder 2.9.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using method_source 0.9.2
Using puma 4.3.1
Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
Using thor 1.0.1
Using railties 6.0.2.1
Using sprockets 4.0.0
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 6.0.2.1
Using rubyzip 2.0.0
Using sassc 2.2.1
Using tilt 2.0.10
Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
Using sass-rails 6.0.0
Using selenium-webdriver 3.142.6
Using spring 2.1.0
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using sqlite3 1.4.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.2.1
Using web-console 4.0.1
Using webdrivers 4.1.3
Using webpacker 4.2.2
Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 75 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: Spring inserted
* bin/rails: Spring inserted
       rails  webpacker:install
rails aborted!
LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/ffi-1.11.3/lib/ffi_c.so
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'

[...]

/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
/home/franck/code/BTC1M/MY-APP-TEST/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/franck/code/BTC1M/MY-APP-TEST/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
[...]
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
/home/franck/code/BTC1M/MY-APP-TEST/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/franck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/franck/code/BTC1M/MY-APP-TEST/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan: 

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I absolutely don't know how to fix this issue. Does someone have any idea ?

---

EDIT :

I uninstalled RVM, reinstalled bundler and rails, and run `gem pristine --all`, it has fixed the problem. I can now create a new rails app without any issue.

Comment: It happened to me in the past with Docker, and I solved by removing the volume I was storing the gems in. So I suggest trying to empty out the gems folder so they will be freshly re-installed. To know where they are located run `gem env`

Comment: Try creating a separate gemset for this project and reinstall all gems. See if it gives any errors then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install extensions first

`brew install postgresql`

then do

`bundle install`

Comment: i am on Ubuntu so i tried : `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install postgresql` but i already had postgresql installed and it didn't fix my problem.
I can't `bundle install` as i am not in an app repertory (no gemfile) as i am trying to create it